# My code is failing to go through the whole array. I am basically to write the function that counts how many times the item in array was repeated

Tags: arrays, templates

My code is failing to go through the whole array. I am basically to write the function that counts how many times the item in array was repeated.

**This the header file**

```
// how_many.h file 

#ifndef HOW_MANY_H 
#define HOW_MANY_H 
#include <array>

const int kMaxSize = 20; template

T HowMany(const std::array<T, kMaxSize> number_array, int values) 
{ 
 T same_item = number_array[0];

   for(int i = 1; i < kMaxSize; i++)
    {

    if(same_item == 9)
    {
        same_item++;
    }
    return same_item;

     }
}

#endif
```

**This is the main.cpp folder**

```
// main.cpp folder 
 #include <iostream>
 #include <array>
 #include "how_many.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

// calling the HowMany function with int parameters
array<int , kMaxSize> counts = {1,9,81,24,2,12,46,12,9,10,0,1,0,12};

int array_Size = 14;        // to hold the size of the array
int count_Value;           // to catch the count value returned from the function

count_Value = HowMany(counts,array_Size);

cout << "The value is " << count_Value << endl;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Welcome to So, please edit your question and place code in `code` blocks, your `}` is outside the blocks, also see how do I ask a good question [ask], take our [tour], for editors, it needs community edit. Also write short and to the point title.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.